# makefile : applying a single rule to a bunch of target

Tags: makefile

I'm starting to learn how to write makefiles and I can't find an existing topic related to my question, so apologies if it already exists.

As of now, it looks like this (and it works) :

```
INSTALL_DIR = $(realpath /home/$(USER)/bin/)
SRC         = $(realpath ./)
script      = $(SRC)/foo.sh
TAR         = $(INSTALL_DIR)/foo

all : $(TAR)

$(TAR) : $(script)
    ln -s $^ $@
```

What I would like to do is to use a minimum number of lines to generate symbolic links (that is, applying the existing rule for building TAR) to *every* bash script (that is $(SRC)*.sh)  in the same fashion as I did for the first one ('foo.sh') here.
I could just make 'script' and 'TAR' like variable for every script manually but I'm sure there must be a better way. Little help ?

Comment: You have two problems: 1) constructing a list of all scripts in the working directory, and 2) constructing a link for each script on the list. Which problem would you like help with? (P.S. and how do you want to name the links?)

Comment: Unless defining
     TAR=(wildcard $(SRC)*.sh)
is the correct way to do it, I would like help on the first issue.
I have no idea how to manage the second, so I'd like help with this as well.
I would like the links to have the same names as the files they refer to but without any extension, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we must find the scripts:

```
INSTALL_DIR = bin # there is no need for a full path here
SRC = $(realpath ./)

SCRIPTS := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.sh) # /some/path/foo.sh /some/path/bar.sh /some/path/baz.sh
SCRIPTS := $(notdir $(SCRIPTS)) # foo.sh bar.sh baz.sh
```

Note my use of ":=" rather than "=". You can read about the difference [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors), but usually ":=" is better.

Now for the targets, the links we're trying to construct:

```
TARGETS := $(basename $(SCRIPTS)) # foo bar baz
TARGETS := $(addprefix $(INSTALL_DIR)/, $(TARGETS)) # bin/foo bin/bar bin/baz
```

The rules:

```
all: $(TARGETS)

$(INSTALL_DIR)/%: $(SRC)/%.sh
    ln -s $< $@
```

That last rule is quite general. We could restrict it to the target list we defined:

```
$(TARGETS): $(INSTALL_DIR)/%: $(SRC)/%.sh
    ln -s $< $@
```

Further refinements are possible, once this is working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I almost got it to work. The only remaining issue is that when I define TARGETS as $INSTALL_DIR$(basename SCRIPTS) (not the other way around, but it does not matter), I get a redundant path because apparently basename only cuts out the extension but not the complete absolute path that is return using wildcard. How can I go around this ? (I apology for the trivial nature of my questions but I really get lost in the documentation)

Comment: @Neutrinoceros: Sorry, that was my oversight. Try `TARGETS := $(INSTALL_DIR)$(basename $(notdir $(SCRIPTS)))`, and if that doesn't work we'll go through it step by step.

Comment: It doesn't.
The thing is, $(INSTALL_DIR)$(basename $(notdir $(SCRIPTS))) returns
"~/bin/foo bar baz", so if I use __make clean__ (defined as rm $(TARGETS)) to uninstall, it's going to remove the first link but won't find the others because it's looking for them in the current directory.
More importantly, trying to recover the installation using __make__ yields the following error:
**no rule to make target**.
I except the fault lies in the pattern definition which may be confusing because I don't want to specify any extension. Is there a way to work around that ?

Comment: Ok I got the first issue solved using addprefix as follow
`TARGETS     = $(addprefix $(INSTALL_DIR)/, $(basename $(notdir $(SCRIPTS))))`
Still struggling with the pattern part though.

Comment: I should have thought of that-- I really am making a lot of mistakes this week. But can you explain what you mean by *"I don't want to specify any extension"*? You specify the extension ".sh" when you search for scripts; would you prefer not to? Do you want Make to treat any file of the form `*.*` as a script?

Comment: Ok this one in on me. I meant I don't want my _links_ to have any extension, the goal is to make them behave as usual bash commands from terminal. But yes, I still want to specify that the corresponding dependency for "foo" is "foo.sh".
edit : I deleted the duplicate question, sorry for that and thank you very much for the help you provided thusfar.

Comment: @Neutrinoceros: All right, I've completely revised -- and tested -- my answer. That ought to do it, but if not, we'll tear it down and build up in stages.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks again for your patience and commitement :-)
Thank you also for the documentation, I actually meant to ask the difference between `=`and `:=`
**nb** should I make edits to the original post to include your solution of mark the topic as closed ?

Comment: @Neutrinoceros: No, you can leave it just as it is. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a pattern rule.   Something like:

```
SCRIPTS := foo bar xxx yyy

all: $(SCRIPTS)  

% : %.sh
    ln -s $< $@
```

Note that `$(SCRIPTS)` can also be populated by `$(wildcard ...)` if none of the scripts are generated by make (otherwise, `$(SCRIPTS)` would be missing any file that did not exist when make was first invoked).